# Inherit XML interface / set activity / setView

Tags: xml, android-activity, f#, setcontentview

I want to learn more about phone app programming. But i want to learn it via F#.

In Java you can inherit an XML interface like this:

```
public class DanishRegisterSite extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register_denmark_ui);

    }

}
```

The guides on this subject regarding F# are very few. So i hope someone here can tell me how would i go about setting the content view of an xml document like above but in F# ?

Thx

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you look? What specific problems did you encounter?

Comment: problem is i looked everywhere and found nothing. visual studio have given me a tiny hint that i am looking into atm.

Comment: Please give more specifics. Are asking how to declare a class inheriting from another class? Are you asking how to override a method? What is the "tiny hint"? Make your question clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will set the view of your F# based phone android App

```
namespace setView 

    // library adding
    open System 
    open Android.App
    open Android.Content
    open Android.OS
    open Android.Runtime
    open Android.Views
    open Android.Widget

    [<Activity (Label = "setView", MainLauncher = true)>]
    type MainActivity () =
        inherit Activity()

        override this.OnCreate (bundle) = base.OnCreate (bundle)
                                          this.SetContentView (Resource_Layout.Hello)
```